# Google APIs Explorer does not display using localhost

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python

Google APIs Explorer will not display content using localhost

Launching Chrome with the fix: --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080 doesn't work as "--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure" is not a valid command line option for Chrome.

The resolution on https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api says to use that flag

[image: Unsupported flag]

Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: If you could [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Component=Endpoints), that would be helpful. Please include your Chrome and OS versions.

Comment: Issue 12713 #9 has the same problem. I'm on Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit) on Windows 7. It says there not to be a 'me too'

Comment: I was able to repro the warning, but APIs still loaded.

Comment: I have the same issue. My chrome version is 51.0.2704.84 m and Windows 7.